# Magento2 : Credit card validations on a custom form not working

Tags: magento2.2, payment, form-validation, magento-2.2.5

I am trying to add Credit card validations on Custom payment form

```
 <form id="testForm" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
            First name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" class="required-entry" >
            <br>
           credit card:<br>
            <input type="text" name="creditcard" class="required-entry validate-cc-number">
            CCV:<br>
            <input type="text" name="cvv" class="required-entry validate-cc-cvn">
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

I have also added dependency for it

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'jquery.bootstrap',
    'payment',
    'mage/validation'
], function ($, bootstrap, payment, validation) { }
```

**validate-cc-number**  is not working as expected when input is empty is gives error

> Please enter a valid credit card number

but even if i input 'TestCard' as input it validates and shows no error , for cvv it does not even throws an error message

What am i missing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Credit card validations to work you need to have input with value as card type

```
 <input type="hidden" value="" id="cc_type"> //value can VI,MC,AI,DN as per card entered
<input id="ccno" name="ccno" class="form-text form-control ccno validate-cc-number"
   data-validate="{
   'required-number':true,
   'validate-cc-number':'#cc_type',
   'validate-cc-type':'#cc_type'
   }"
   >
</div>
```

Same is required for CVV

```
<input name="cccvv" id="cccvv" class="form-text form-control cccvv "
   data-validate="{
   'required-number':true,
   'validate-cc-cvn':'#cc_type'
   }">
</div>
```

and for expriry date check

```
<select name="cc_exp_month" id="cc_exp_month" class="cc_exp_month"
   data-validate="{
   'required':true,
   'validate-cc-exp':'#cc_exp_yr'
   }"
   > //put year select as required and in month vlidation put year select id .Magento expects in format of YYYY
<select name="cc_exp_yr" id="cc_exp_yr" class="form-select form-control cc_exp_yr" data-validate="{required:true}">
```